# splitting a date string by index to string using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Hi I have a few syntax problems as I build a date from a string that looks like

My code :

```
paramCheckDate = "01/14/2022"

CheckDateYYYYMMDD = paramCheckDate.split["/"][2].toString() + paramCheckDate.split["/"][1].toString() + paramCheckDate.split["/"][0].toString()
```

I would like to build another string in the format YYYYMMDD. Splitting by index and then .toString but I have syntax errors if I can get some guidance that would be awesome!

Comment: I think you want `split("/")`

Comment: `String.split` is a function, so you should call it with parentheses not brackets.  `paramCheckDate.split(...)`

Comment: `paramCheckDate.split("/").reverse().join("");` I like to use this instead. It is clean.

Comment: There is another mistake here though, because the source format seems to be M/D/Y and not D/M/Y, so reversing won't yield the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have `['/']` instead of `('/')` - `String.prototype.split` is a function that you have to call, not an array/object that you have to index.
2. There is no need for `toString()`, the parts of the strings are already - well - strings.
3. Your example shows that you want to convert MM/DD/YYYY to YYYYMMDD, however (assuming you fixed #1) you are actually converting it to YYYYDDMM. You'd have to use the third, then the *first* and then the *second* part. (I am assuming MM/DD/YYYY as source because there is no 14th month of the year.)
4. It would be more performant (and easier to read) not to call `split` 3 times. Instead, you can split it once and then join:

```js
const [m, d, y] = paramCheckDate.split('/')
const CheckDateYYYYMMDD = y + m + d
```

Answer (score 0):

Square braces are for array access, round braces are for function calls.

Use `paramCheckDate.split("/")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below Regular Expression to replace your source string to your required format

```js
const CheckDateYYYYMMDD = paramCheckDate.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/,"$3$1$2");
```

Comment: While this works, it is hard to read and unnecessarily slow (approx. 6x slower than splitting once and then concatenating), so I think with this we would be teaching a bad habit here...